# Accessor to a vector's last element in a map (C++)

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdvector

I'm trying to assign an accessor to the last element of a vector inside a map. What I'm doing is as follows;

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<double> > test;
test.insert(std::make_pair("smth",std::vector<double>() ));
double* bla = &(test["smth"].back());
(*bla) += 5.
```

what I want to do is, basically, access to the last element of the vector inside the map and modify it through the accessor `bla`. However, I'm constantly getting a segmentation violation. So I thought maybe I need to initialize the double inside the vector so I set it to zero but still the same issue. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You have an empty vector, so `.back()` method call causes undefined behaviour

Comment: In addition, `.back() ` -- returns a reference to the item.  There is no need to use pointers.  Just assign the return value of `back()` to a `double &`.

Comment: Can you show the minimal complete code that reproduces your current issue? The current question has one problem - that using `back()` on an empty vector is UB - but you're also asking about some other code you didn't show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example there is no `back` that you could access. The vector is empty: `std::vector<double>()`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back):

> Calling back on an empty container causes undefined behavior.

Further note that there is no point to use a pointer to `back`. The method already returns a reference (if the element is present). You should add something to the vector before you can modify it, eg:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<double> > test;
auto x = test.insert(std::make_pair("smth",std::vector<double>() ));
x.first->push_back(0);
x.first->back() += 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector::back()` function can't be used on empty container, It means `std::vector<double>` should not be empty and must be populate with at least one value.
Another point is, in this case you can use more effective function `std::map::emplace_hint` to do the same things as follows,

```
 std::map<std::string, std::vector<double> > test;
 test.emplace_hint(test.end(), "smth", 1);
 double* bla = &(test["smth"].back());
 (*bla) += 5.;
```